# flink aggregation with window AND state

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm looking for a way to implement aggregation/fold function on a window **that also have a state**.
I understand how to aggregate on a window, and how to use key/global state - but not both.

Just to be clear, when I say a window with state - I mean that **the state should be initialized (nullified) every time the window is changed/moved**.

For example: I want to count the number of events keyed by event type every 5 minutes. But in addition to event type (which is the window key) the event has some id field - and I would like to count each id only once - so I need to save a state of all the ids I've already counted in that window.

Is there a simple way to do this in Flink?

Answer (score 2):

Flink has a RichReduceFunction, which will give you access to state that is global across all windows for a given key. If you need per-window state, see [[Flink-5929]](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3479) which will be part of Flink 1.3.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm not sure I fully understand, but does [Flink-5929](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3479) will implement a state reset whenever one window period is finished and another started?

Comment: Yes, the window state available via Flink-5929 is scoped to a specific window instance and a specific key.